# How to use a function in if else

Tags: python, function

```
 def getmessages(_,m):
    coin = ""
    if m.chat.id == boticindneme:
      coin += m.text
    return coin
 if getmessages(_,m) == "something":
```

when I use this it gives the error _ is not defined so how can I use a function in if else

Comment: Where did you think `_` (or `m`, for that matter) _would_ be defined? Why does that function take two arguments but ignore the first one?

Comment: if you want to ignore the value by `_` what is common in other languages, omit the function argument

Comment: Ok, just because the function `getmessages()` has `(_,m)` as the names of its two parameters, doesn't mean that you as the client have to use those names in *your* code.

Answer (score 2):

That is strange code. As a convention, python programs use `_` to denote a variable that you have to put in to make a program work, but don't really need. An example is a function that returns multiple variables but you don't want them all. Suppose you wanted the second thing in a string, you could do

```
foo = "1,2,3"
_, bar, _ = foo.split(",", maxsplit=2)
print(bar)
```

Python would unpack the resulting `["1", "2", "3"]` into `_`, then `bar`, then `_` again. But you don't care about `_` so its okay to overwrite it.

But to put it into function parameter is weird. You are requiring a parameter that you don't use. That's harsh!

When you define a function, you are creating names that the function will use for its parameters, not what outside code needs to call things.

```
def getmessages(_,m):
    coin = ""
    if m.chat.id == boticindneme:
        coin += m.text
    return coin
```

This doesn't create variables outside of the function, you need to create those yourself. Since the function doesn't actually use `_`, you can put anything into it. `None` seems like a good choice. And since we don't know what this `m` thing is, I'll make something up.

```
foo =  WhateverThatMThingIs()

if getmessages(None, foo) == "something":
    print('okay")
```